# How can I find hdfs directory along with file sizes using Python?

Tags: python

I want to find the size of a folder along with files inside that folder in hdfs. I tried using hdfs module but that module is not available in my cluster and permissions to install it. Is there any other approach to find the sizes?

Comment: check `pathlib.Path(<path>).glob(<pattern>)` for find the `hdf` files and [`Path.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) for the filesizes